# How to loop through htmlcollection object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, htmlcollection

I have looked at almost every question that has been asked here about htmlcollection.

So I have a div and I am fetching data and creating  divs inside this div with ajax so they are not hardcoded.

this is how div look like before I fetch the data

```
    <div id="tivvits"></div>
```

this is how div#tivvits looks like after I call function show_all_tivvits();
show_all_tivvits() is a function where I create a ajax request and create new divs
such as div#tivvit-21, div#tivvit-22, etc.

```
    <div id="tivvits">
        <div id="tivvit-19" class="grid-container">...</div>
        <div id="tivvit-20" class="grid-container">...</div>
    </div>
```

this is part of the js file

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    
        show_all_tivvits();
        var t = document.getElementById('tivvits');
        const j = t.getElementsByClassName("grid-container");
        const k = Array.prototype.slice.call(j)
        console.log(k);
        for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
            console.log(k[i]);
        }

    });
```

what I wanted to do in show_all_tivvits() function is I want to get the divs that are already in the div#tivvits and that way I am not gonna create them again but the problem is when I use `console.log()` to print out `document.getElementById('tivvits').getElementsByClassName('grid-container')` there are items in the htmlcollection but when I print out length it returns 0.

one more thing when I open inspect>source in chrome my index.php doesn't have updated div#tivvits.
I have tried almost every way to loop this htmlcollection but it is not working.

list of things I have tried;

```
Array.from(links)

Array.prototype.slice.call(links)

[].forEach.call(links, function (el) {...});

HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];

HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Comment: why by id and also class? That doesn't make sense at all

Comment: Just use `let links = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-container"); links.forEach(link => {console.log(link)})`

Comment: @Alex i was thinking since they are child of div#tivvits that's why I did that. So you are suggesting that I can do `document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')` right?

Comment: imo you should make a `tivvits` object, which has get, render, show methods then store the values/component in an array which you can check before render, you're trying to do too much in one or two functions

Comment: No I would say use something like pthohtep has mentioned document.querySelectorAll will do a good hob

Comment: Since `show_all_tivvits` function is making an AJAX request, the code following the function call returns the HTML before the response could be added. That means that there are no nodes in the inside your target div. What you should do is take the code after the function invocation and put it in a function that you can use a callback for the AJAX response. Depending on how the AJAX request is sent, you need to determine how to define a callback (or success callback) for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear, but are you looking for something like this?

```
targets = document.querySelectorAll('#tivvits > .grid-container')
for (let target of targets)
  {console.log(target.id)}
```

This should select all `<div>` nodes which are direct children of the `<div id="tivvits">` node and have a `class` attribute with the value `"grid-container"`, and extract from them the attribute value of the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The world has moved on.

The older versions

```
const arrayLikeCollection = Array.prototype.slice.call(htmlCollection)
```

and

```
[].forEach.call(htmlCollection, function (el) {...});
```

could be written

```
[...htmlCollection].arrayMethod(....)
```

Then we got an update to htmlCollection so it supported .forEach out of the box. However the OTHER array methods like map, filter, some and every still needs the hmtlCollection to be cast to an arrayLike collection.

In 2024, the consensus is to use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) due to the very descriptive name.

It is my method of choice too now, since the array spread can generate annoying errors if your statement on the line above does not have a semicolon:

```
const collection = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')
[...collection].someMethod(...) // the [] is seen as belonging to the line before
```

So here is the currently recommended way

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the elements are available
  const getIds = () => {
    const gridContainers = document.querySelectorAll("#tivvits .grid-container");
    const ids = Array.from(gridContainers).map(div => div.id);
    return ids;
  };
  const idsAtLoadTime = getIds(); // can be called elsewhere, like at the end of an AJAX call
  console.log(idsAtLoadTime)
});
```

```html
<div id="tivvits">
  <div id="tivvit-19" class="grid-container">...</div>
  <div id="tivvit-20" class="grid-container">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and I hardcoded div#tivvit-19 and div#tivvit-20 and it worked but since they are actually not hardcoded somehow document can't see them.

Comment: `<div id="tivvits"></div>` is initially empty then, In the load event listener i call show_all_tivvits() function which make a ajax request and I create div#tivvit-19, div#tivvit-20, etc. inside div#tivvits.

Comment: Please update your question with what you ACTUALLY want to do since I think you are making things too difficult for yourself

Comment: but this is actually what i want to do tho

Comment: See update if you are still interested